# How (if possible) can I use FLTK within Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, installation, fltk

I have mostly been using Visual Studio Code for my responses to exercises and drills in Programming: Practices and Principles (2nd Ed.) by Bjarne Stroustrup. I will soon be starting Chapters 12 through 17, a section of the book that involves the use of FLTK.

I believe Stroustrup assumes that users will be using FLTK within Visual Studio. However, I am wondering whether it is possible to use/install/run (not sure of the proper terminology) FLTK within Visual Studio Code. If so, any advice or documentation would be much appreciated, as I'm currently not finding any guides for doing this on the web. If not, just let me know and I'll try using Visual Studio Community for these exercises.

Thank you as always for your input!

Comment: Hello, I have the same question as you at Chapter 12. Did you find an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63671263/13156261) if it can be of any help.