# FLTK library with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, fltk

I'm trying to install FLTK library for Chapter 12 from Programming Principles and Practice,
but the build command is not recognized. What should I do? Thanks!

```
PS D:\3. Programming\C++\GUI\fltk-1.3.5> make
make : The term 'make' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ make
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually feel more comfortable with Makefiles, so I set VS Code for using the Makefile within my projects. I have done the following steps after installing FLTK.

1. I create a directory containing all my source files, headers and so on. Let's say that I have a `FLTK_ex` folder with `hello.cpp` and its `Makefile`
2. I open VS Code, then `File->Open` and I select the folder `FLTK_ex`
3. From the `Terminal` menu, I select `Configure Default Build Task...`: in the menu that appears I select `Create tasks.json file from template` and then `Others`
4. A default json file appears, I modify it as

   ```
   {
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "tasks": [
       {
           "label": "Build",
           "type": "shell",
           "command": "Make",
           "problemMatcher": [],
           "group": {
               "kind": "build",
               "isDefault": true
           }
       }
   ]
   ```

   }
5. For compiling, go to `Terminal` menu and select `Run Build Task...`
6. For running the program, in the `Run` menu select `Run without debugging`, `C++`
7. A `launch.json` file appears: modify it as (where `myprogram` is the executable name)

   ```
    {

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "(lldb) Launch",
           "type": "cppdbg",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "${workspaceFolder}/myprogram",
           "args": [],
           "stopAtEntry": false,
           "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
           "environment": [],
           "externalConsole": false,
           "MIMode": "lldb"
       }
       ]
   }
   ```
8. For effectevely run the program, in `Run` menu select again `Run without debugging`.

I have FLTK 1.3.5, macOS Catalina 10.15.5, clang version 11.0.3, VS Code 1.47.

---

In order to use FLTK in VS Code, I just followed the instruction (in `Readme.OSX.txt`) for simply installing FLTK library, there is a similar file for Windows systems (`README.MSWindows.txt`).

The guidelines for writing a `Makefile` for `FLTK` are [here](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/basics.html#basics_makefile), if you need more insights on `Makefile`s you can find a complete guide [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction) or a shorter introduction [here](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Ezxu2/acms60212-40212/Makefile.pdf).

---

Comment: Thanks Eddymage for your answer... could you please explain how to install FLTK in VS Code and how to make the Makefile? I bounced around between CMake and Make, trying to figure out which one to use... and indeed Make seems a better choice for a simpler project. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Theodore, yep, I added more info in my answer: I hope that they are useful.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which version of Visual Studio you are using.

1. Go to the IDE directory, look for your version of visual studio then look for the fltk solution.  Start the solution in Visual Studio.
2. By default, whenever you start an FLTK solution from the distribution, the solution configuration is Debug Cairo.  Change this to Debug or Release
3. Check the startup project - it should be the one called Demo.
4. Start the build - it should build all the test executables too.

Comment: Thanks Cup, but I'm asking for VS Code not VS... 
It's the latest Visual Studio Code Insiders...

Answer (score -1):

```
<p>This works for me.</p>
<p>Watch the library list. -X11 has to be before -lfltk</p>
<p>Not sure about the tabs, but leave them in.</p>
<h2>c_cpp_properties.json</h2>

<pre><code>
{
    "env": {
        "myDefaultIncludePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}",
            "${workspaceFolder}/include"
        ],
        "myCompilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++"
    },
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "include paths",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "includePath": [

                "/usr/include/cairo",
                "/usr/include/glib-2.0", 
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include",
                "/usr/include/pixman-1",
                "/usr/include/uuid",
                "/usr/include/freetype2", 
                "/usr/include/libpng16",
                "/usr/include/freetype2",
                "/usr/include/libpng16",
                "/usr/include/cairo",
                "/usr/include/glib-2.0", 
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include",
                "/usr/include/pixman-1",
                "/usr/include/uuid",
                "/usr/include/freetype2",
                "/usr/include/libpng16"

            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
<p></p>

</code></pre><p></p>

<h2>launch.json</h2>

<pre><code>

    {
        // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
        // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
        // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
    
            {
                "name": "debug with gdb (no build)",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "args": [],
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "environment": [],
                "externalConsole": false,
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "setupCommands": [
                    {
                        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    }
                ],
                "preLaunchTask": "",
                "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
            }
        ]
      }


</code></pre>

<h2>tasks.json</h2>

<pre><code>
    {
        "version":"2.0.0",
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "gcc debug build active file - with GTK",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": [          
            "-g",
    
                  "-pthread",
                  "-I/usr/include/cairo",
                  "-I/usr/include/glib-2.0", 
                  "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include",
                  "-I/usr/include/pixman-1",
                  "-I/usr/include/uuid",
                  "-I/usr/include/freetype2", 
                  "-I/usr/include/libpng16",
                  "-I/usr/include/freetype2",
                  "-I/usr/include/libpng16",
                  "-I/usr/include/cairo",
                  "-I/usr/include/glib-2.0", 
                  "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include",
                  "-I/usr/include/pixman-1",
                  "-I/usr/include/uuid",
                  "-I/usr/include/freetype2",
                  "-I/usr/include/libpng16",
    
            "${file}",
                  "-lX11",
                  "-lm",
                  "-lfltk",
                  "-Wall",
                  "-o",
                  "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "/usr/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
      }     
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Code samples or revised code should include a description of what you changed to fix the problem.